# Which function is called in a C program?

Tags: debugging, gcc

I am trying to figure out which exact function is called (from which include file) when I call a library function.

So, I have this program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int twice(int input) {
  int output;
  output = input * 2;
  return output;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Hello World and %f\n", sin(1));
  printf("Output: %d\n", twice(3));
  printf("Here is the end of the program... %d\n", 3);
}
```

I want to see which printf is called. (I know in this case, it is the one in stdio.h, but this is just an example.)

I compile the file:

```
g++ -g test.cpp
```

and then do dump the assembly code

```
objdump --source a.out > test.objdump
```

In the test.objdump, I see lines like

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  400528: 55                    push   %rbp
  400529: 48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40052c: 48 83 ec 10           sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400530: 89 7d fc              mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  400533: 48 89 75 f0           mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
  printf("Hello World and %f\n", sin(1));
  400537: f2 0f 10 05 91 01 00  movsd  0x191(%rip),%xmm0   #4006d0<__dso_handle+0x50>
  40053e: 00
  40053f: bf 88 06 40 00        mov    $0x400688,%edi
  400544: b8 01 00 00 00        mov    $0x1,%eax
  400549: e8 c2 fe ff ff        callq  400410 <printf@plt>
  printf("Output: %d\n", twice(3));
  40054e: bf 03 00 00 00        mov    $0x3,%edi
  400553: e8 bc ff ff ff        callq  400514 <_Z5twicei>
  400558: 89 c6                 mov    %eax,%esi
  40055a: bf 9c 06 40 00        mov    $0x40069c,%edi
  40055f: b8 00 00 00 00        mov    $0x0,%eax
  400564: e8 a7 fe ff ff        callq  400410 <printf@plt>
  printf("Here is the end of the program... %d\n", 3);
  400569: be 03 00 00 00        mov    $0x3,%esi
  40056e: bf a8 06 40 00        mov    $0x4006a8,%edi
  400573: b8 00 00 00 00        mov    $0x0,%eax
  400578: e8 93 fe ff ff        callq  400410 <printf@plt>
  40057d: b8 00 00 00 00        mov    $0x0,%eax
}
```

It seems like the address of the printf function is given in callq line: 400410. But when I do

```
addr2line -e a.out 0x400410
```

(I tried 400410 without 0x too), I get

```
??:0
```

which does not give me the location of the printf function. Can somebody point out the error in my process. Is there some option to g++ I am not passing?

Really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: N.B: stdio.h contains a *declaration* of `printf()` not a *definition*. What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve (and why are you using g++ to compile C)?

Comment: The real problem I want to solve is in a big code base. There is a function call (say xyz()) and the function is contained in one of the 100 or so included files. I want to determine where is the function (declaration) located.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, if the standard library was compiled with `-g`, would we see the corresponding line number? I think that's it.

Comment: @YogiSharma, So you are looking for `xyz()`, or some other function that you (or your colleagues) have written? i.e. you're not actually interested in standard library functions such as `printf`?

Comment: Also, the easiest thing is to just use something like `grep` ! Never mind all the compilation and so on!

Comment: @YogiSharma: OK... this makes more sense. I've provided an answer. I'm sorry to hear that you're having to deal with a source file that `#include`s about a hundred headers! That's immense!

Comment: @AaronMcDaid There is a reason I am not using grep. Same function can appear in multiple files (say 10 files), and only one of them in included in my example code (out of 100 included files, across various source files). It becomes a bit hard to figure out using grep.

Comment: @YogiSharma: "a bit hard", yes, but not impossible, once you filter out the *invocations* of the function. Anyway, my answer, using the C preprocessor, deals with this.

Comment: I see. Are you looking for the declaration, or the definition? I think you said declaration, but I think mean definition. For example: `void xyz(void) { printf("zyz\n"); }` is a definition, and you should only have one of them. But `void xyz(void);` is a declaration, and you are entitled to have as many of them as you like (as long as they agree with each other).

Comment: ... reading @Johnsyweb 's answer, I get the impression you want to find the (first) declaration. And you don't care about actually finding the definition? Maybe you want both?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: What I want to find is the location the [step] command (while running the [gdb]) will jump to when I am running the program under gdb. So, that is the _definition_.

Comment: OK, you want the *definition*. I don't think you can do that for standard functions like `printf` without downloading the source code for those functions. Typically, your computer will have lots of *header files* for standard functions, but not the definitions of those functions. Maybe you are looking for the definition of a function you (or a colleague) wrote? Maybe it's time to stop using abstract examples and tell us a real function name that you are looking for now. Are you looking for `printf`, or for `yogis_function`, or for something else?

Comment: ...and this is why people use IDEs with a "Go To Declaration/Definition" feature. It makes their life about 1,000 times easier.

Comment: As @AaronMcDaid points out, you may not always have the *definition* on your computer. Consider definitions that are written in *other languages*, or those to be resolved at runtime. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You're compiling your code into object code, and then dumping the assembly code from the object code. At that point, the code has not been linked together by the linker, and so `printf` is merely a symbol in the Procedure Linkage Table. Only when the program has been linked will that definition appear.

EDIT: On second glance at your compiler options, I see the executable is being linked together. If you do have debugging symbols built in, you may need to specify which section you wish to use with `addr2line`.

As for using `printf`, I believe `addr2line` can only find the definitions of functions local to your executable, not function defined by external libraries. From `test.cpp`'s perspective, `printf` exists outside of itself and cannot have a line under which it was defined, because that will only be recorded by the library being linked. If that library (glibc in this case) was not compiled as a debugging build, you cannot know what file and line number it was defined on.

Comment: Joshua K: [http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Addr2line] seems to suggest that the location of functions from external libraries is also recorded in the executable, but this does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: In those examples, `_init` is built into the program through the C run time as object code by the compiler. `printf` on the other hand is within glibc.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find the *declaration* of `printf()` (in C or C++, it's not clear from your question which you're using), you could do:

```
g++ -E test.cpp | less
```

Where `-E` means:

> -E                       Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link

Then search forwards <kbd>/</kbd> for `printf` to find the declaration (it must be declared before it's used and so must be the first hit). Then search backwards  <kbd>?</kbd> for `^#`, to find from which file this has been included.

No compilation, linking or object dumping is required!

I also recommend checking out [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/) and [`ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), both of which can be used to find symbols in large source trees with great efficiency.

---

Following further comments...

Finding the definition by *compiling and linking* your code may not always be possible. You've seen this with `printf()`, which you didn't build and may not exist on your computer. Consider also definitions that are written in other languages, or those to be resolved at runtime.

[`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/) and [`ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) are likely to be the best approach for you.

Good luck!

Comment: It appears that we should be looking for the definition - see the latest comments on the question. (Good answer otherwise).

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Ah. I posted my answer after Yogi commented "I want to determine where is the function (declaration) located." In that case, my last paragraph is probably the best advice that I can offer. That and learning to discriminate between C and C++ and Declarations, Definitions and Invocations.

Answer (score 1):

addr2line can find only definitions contained in given executable, therefore it won't say anything about `printf` giving in answer:

```
rafal:~/test$ addr2line -f 0x400448
??
??:0
rafal:~/test$ addr2line -f 0x400554
_Z5twicei
/home/rafal/test/c.cpp:4
```

For finding information about functions in shared libraries as well, you can use gdb

```
gdb a.out
(gdb) info symbol 0x400448
printf@plt in section .plt of /home/rafal/test/a.out
(gdb) info symbol 0x400554
twice(int) in section .text of /home/rafal/test/a.out
```

Comment: Thanks Rafal. What extra information does gdb give in this example. The information from [info symbol] also appears in the objdump file. May be I am missing something.

Comment: GDB runs the executable which links it in memory. When you invoke `info 0x400448` it looks up the symbol at that address (which resolves to `printf`) and notes that it is within the PLT section of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g++ -g -static test.cpp
```

That should remove all confusion for you.

Without `-static` gcc links against *shared* libraries. This means that functions like printf are not in your program at all, but are loaded from /lib at run time. That's more space efficient, but is perhaps slightly slower (although your system as a whole will run faster). You can examine the contents of a running program with GDB, but beware that sharing code means there's a lot of confusing gubbins like GOTs and PLTs and such to wade through.

Compiling as a static binary pulls in all the system functions and places them into your program. Note that this does not work with all possible libraries (if they don't provide a static alternative).